# TypeError "Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>."

Tags: python, django, cs50

I am working on an auction application in Django.  When I try to create a new listing I get a *Type Error* saying,

> **Type Error at/create>** "Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>".

It also highlights views.py, line 81:

> "viewListing = Listing.objects.get.(pk=id)".

What input should I pass to make this work properly?  I expected to be redirected to the index view which would include the newly created listing.

Here is the relevant view from views.py:

```
@login_required
def create(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
            "categories": categories
        })
    else:
        title = request.POST\["title"\]
        description = request.POST\["description"\]
        image = request.POST\["image"\]
        price = request.POST\["price"\]
        category = request.POST\["category"\]
        categories = Category.objects.get(categoryType=category)
        sessionUser = request.user
        viewListing = Listing.objects.get(pk=id)
        viewListing.watchlist.add(sessionUser)
        
        bid = Bid(bid=float(price), user=sessionUser)
        bid.save()
        
        listing = Listing(
            title=title,
            description=description,
            image=image,
            price=bid,
            category=categories,
            owner=sessionUser
        )
        listing.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(index))
```

Here is urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = \[
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
path("register", views.register, name="register"),
path("create", views.create, name="create"),
path("categories/", views.categories, name="categories"),
path("filter/\<int:category_id\>", views.filter, name="filter"),
path("listing/\<int:id\>", views.listing, name="listing"),
path("remove/\<int:id\>", views.remove, name="remove"),
path("add/\<int:id\>", views.add, name="add"),
path("watchlist", views.watchlist, name="watchlist"),
path("comment/\<int:id\>", views.comment, name="comment"),
path("bid/\<int:id\>", views.bid, name="bid"),
path("close/\<int:id\>", views.close, name="close")
\]
```

And just in case, here is the models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Bid(models.Model):
    bid = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="userBid", null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.bid}"

class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.ForeignKey(Bid, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="currentbid", null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user", null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=900)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="category", null=True, blank=True)
    watchlist = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name="watchlist")
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="author")
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="comment")
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.author} comment on {self.listing}"
```

Comment: This error occurred because `id` variable is not defined in your code and you are trying to access that variable also `id` is the default Python-inbuilt function(https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) so your code is using that function and giving the type error.
Just review your code and give the proper id for which you want to access the listing.